# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning, on xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

When ever I try to push my app to my ipad or ipod to test them I get this error...

alignment lost in merging tentative definition _resultbuffer.

What is it? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What does "push my app" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess here, apologies if I'm too far off the mark:

On the ARM processor alignment can be an issue, particularly if you're accessing a variables in an unaligned manner, I suspect this is what you're seeing:

Here's a couple links that might see you through this:

- [gcc type-attributes documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) (Yes, I know its compiling with clang, this still may help)
- [Basically the same thing from ARM's documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/Cacjcjce.html?resultof=%22alignment%22%20%22align%22%20)
- [A pretty good write-up about ARM alignment and how to avoid problems](http://netwinder.osuosl.org/users/b/brianbr/public_html/alignment.html)

Most flavors of ARM will automatically 'fix' this by adjusting the alignment on the fly, however this is configurable. The down-side is it causes a CPU interrupt to handle it, so if you're doing this over and over it'll slow things down. I haven't run into this on iOS, so I can't say for sure what the behavior would be. Odds are its best just to fix it.